# Name of Fibre optic motherboard connector, like ethernet socket?

Tags: connector, optical-fibre

I am trying to find the name of fibre optics cable connector, so a fibre optic cable can be used on my design, does it have a official name? for about the past half hour - an hour I have been googling to find it, but so far have come up with nothing.

Like the connectors used on this internet switch:

[image]

Comment: Photo please...?

Comment: SFP or some variant of.

Answer (score 6):

Your photo appears to be [SFP/SFP+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver) transceivers.

SFP isn't really a connector type, is a transceiver standard. The actual connector (on the switch side) is a board edge connector, the other side can be a wide variety of connectors.

If it's the actual fibre connector you're talking about, probably [LC connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_connector), which is the optical connector used in just about every optical SFP module (LC connectors can be used for both SMF and MMF).

Comment: I would like to be able to get a fibre cable, used in internet, and plug it into my design, instead of using ethernet, since what I am designing it for has no ethernet, we use fibre for every thing. Probably being a bit vague, sorry.

Comment: @Alex I think this answer is fully answering your original question and should be accepted. If you have any other questions - ask them in a different thread.

Comment: @Alex, as long as your signal has balance (ratio of 1's to 0's) and transition density (minimum number of transitions per second) comparable to ethernet, the fiber optic module shouldn't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: This answer might help illustrate why you build your device with a Small Form Pluggable interface and use a SFP for the actual fiber connection: http://superuser.com/questions/397900/why-are-fibre-channel-transceivers-are-not-embedded-into-fibre-channel-card/652378#652378

Comment: @Alex: if I understand you correctly (your terminology is a bit muddled), you want to connect a board to an Ethernet switch via fibre. In which case you should design an SFP/SFP+ slot onto the board, and then you can use whichever SFP module you wish. However, be aware that designing circuits at these speeds is _non-trivial_.

Comment: @uint128_t, I think he wants to use a proprietary protcol, say to connect between two of his proprietary boxes, not connect to ethernet infrastructure (but I could be misunderstanding).

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, I'm not sure. OP, if that's the case, as long as you use something like 64/66b encoding to DC balance/enable clock recovery, you can use SFP modules to transmit arbitrary serial streams between boards at high speed.

Comment: In order to connect a fibre optic cable directly, I would need to use a SFP/SFP+, or is there another way, I do not want to involve ethernet.

Comment: @Alex, what who said? If you actually want to connect to an ethernet switch, you won't be able to do it usefully without sending ethernet protocol signals.

Comment: Does fibre optic not have something like ethernet does, a socket and a receiver IC?

Comment: The fibre optic we are talking about _is_ Ethernet. That is, SFP modules are used for Ethernet (although they can be used for other things). And the SFP module is the transmitter/receiver and the socket.

Comment: The problem it, it has dozens of different ones, and also, the ethernet switch expects several layers of protocol to be present even after converting the signal to digital electrical signals.

Comment: It also depends what data rate you're using. 1 and 2 Gb/s Ethernet use different protocol at the physical medium attach (PMA) layer than 10 Gb/s and higher.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I assume theres a main type used.

Comment: This discussion is getting way far away from the original question. If you have additional, specific, questions please post new questions. If you just want to chat and discuss ideas, consider joining the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).